# ES- Modify sigma before mutate object parameters

Tags: evolutionary-algorithms

I'm reading the book [Introduction to Evolutionary Computing](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9783642072857) and on the chapter about Evolution Strategies said that we have to modify the strategy parameter sigma (standard deviation or mutation step size) before using in to modify the object parameter and I don't understand why.

Why do we have to modify sigma before the mutation of object parameters?

Maybe because if we do it we will have the mutated object parameters and the strategy parameters that have generated them.